# Animate the outer stroke of a view (button)

Tags: android, animation, button, stroke

I'd like to flash/blink the stroke of a button a few times based on a timer.  For example, every 30 seconds flash the stroke 3 times from white to black or some such thing.  Can this be done?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom button layouts like such and put them in the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:startColor="@color/whitesmoke"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/grey3" />
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

where the color grey3 is the border and you can start a timer and add a TimerTask class to your class and then make it run the task every 30 seconds and just change the buttons background from one .xml to another with a different border color.

Comment: In this case, I think what it would have to be is more like two timers.  I was envisioning a quick 1,2,3,4 flash every 30 seconds or whatever.  Like, the three blinks would last a total of 1 second or something.  Just a real fast "get your attention" kind of thing...kind of a reminder.  So, there'd have to be a way to do the blink (one timer) for a certain interval (another timer).

Comment: yea. you could start a countdowntimer every 30 seconds that runs for 1 second and you can set the interval to every 200 milliseconds or something.

Comment: timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 200) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                       //change picture here
                     }
                    }
                 }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                      
                     }
                     
                 }
                }
             };

Comment: i'll have to try it out, i've never used a timer before.  does that code cover both?

Comment: that will cover the blinking of it, the timer to make that happen every 30 seconds will look something like this:           Timer relaxed = new Timer();
relaxed.scheduleAtFixedRate(new timerTask(), 1000, 1000);

Comment: and the class for timer task looks like this:     private class timerTask extends TimerTask
    {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //start countdown timer
  }
     
    } you can put the directly in your class

Comment: I don't know when I'm going to get to try this out, but it sounds correct.  Ill accept so I don't leave you hanging.  Thanks for sticking with it.